# Issue in Integrating In-app to the iOS application

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Is it necessary to submit the app to implement In-App purchase..

We havent yet submitted the app to the app store.. We have added the code for In-App in our app & we actually fetch the products created in Itunes connect via Storekit framework but when we run the app we are getting message as "Invalid Product Identifiers"...

When we browsed the issue on Google & came to know that we need to submit the app to the store & then work on In-app... Is this true??

Kindly help us..

Looking forward for the response at the earliest..

Comment: Just wait a while. Apples sandox server for the InApp purchases do not work all the time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have to submit in order to test (your app is very likely to be not admitted to the store).

If you have recently added the products to iTunes Connect, and then immediately start testing, it will probably not work as it takes some time for the products to penetrate the store. Give it 24-48 hours and try again to see if it fetches your products correctly.

If this still does not happen you probably have an error in your code for fetching the products.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.. We were checking it immediately after adding the products to iTunes connect.. Will wait & then will check...